# Object property missing spaces

Tags: javascript

I have an array as follows:

```
var voxels = [];
```

I also have a variable called `locationId` which contains a string i.e.

```
child.geometry.locationId = "Some random location";
```

When I do

```
voxels.push({x: child.position.x,
             y: child.position.y,
             z: child.position.z,
             t: child.geometry.name,
             id: child.geometry.locationId
            });
```

the string in the `id` variable ends up as `"SomerandomLocation"` when I do

```
 var dataUri = "data:application/json;charset=utf-8," + JSON.stringify(voxels);
 window.open(dataUri, 'mywindow');
```

although I have just noticed that the Url does contain the space but the data on the page does not.

Comment: Define "ends up as". How do you know? What did you do with it? (Hint: this will not happen on its own.)

Comment: Might want to show some code that leads up to the push

Comment: Also there is absolutely no JSON here at all.

Comment: `I have just noticed that the Url does contain the space but the data on the page does not` This is why we narrow problems down before posting them here. There is nothing wrong with your string, or with your object, or with your array. All of that has nothing to do with the problem. The problem you're facing is encoding spaces in a `data:` URI in your particular browser. I'd be tempted to delete this question and try again :)

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I will investigate that. Sorry for wasting your time and thanks.